# Popover arrow styling issues

Tags: html, css, styles

I created a popover but I am having some styling issues with it. I would like the popover's arrow to have red border and transparent background but instead its all red.

I have tried changing `border-bottom` to transparent but then there is no border.

CSS:

```
a {
  position: relative;
}

.popover:before {
  content: "\A";
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  top: -5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%
}

.popover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.popover span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bLsp168v/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using both CSS Pseudo-elements before and after.

```
.popover:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: -15px;
left: 30px;
border-width: 0 15px 15px 15px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: red transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;}

.popover:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: -10px;
left: 36px;
border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #fff transparent;
display: block;}
```